# Restoring 3 numbers $a, b$ and $c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given $4$ numbers $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ and $x_4$ which represent the pairwise sum of $a$, $b$ and $c$ in arbitrary order.

For example:

$$\begin{align}x_1 &= a + b\\x_2 &= a + c\\x_3 &= b + c\\x_4 &= a + b + c\end{align}$$

($x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$ are **known**)

Comment: Find $c$ from the first and last equations, then find $a$, $b$ from the remaining ones.

Comment: are we supposed to find $a,b,c?$

Answer (score 3):

Your system is overdetermined; you don't need $x_4$. Note that $x_1+x_2-x_3=2a$, so
$$a = \frac{x_1+x_2-x_3}2,$$
and the other values follow.